# Windows Perl DB2 database remote connection issue

Tags: windows, perl, db2, dbi, db2-luw

I am trying to make a Perl DB2 remote connection of Windows following instructions [on this IBM site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21297335#caveats).

However, I get an error and it will not work

#### Command console error message

```
install_driver(DB2) failed: Can't load
'C:/Perl64/site/lib/auto/DBD/DB2/Constants/Constants.dll' for module DBD::DB2::Constants: load_file:%1
It is not a valid Win32 application. at C:/Perl64/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 194.
at C:/Perl64/site/lib/DBD/DB2.pm line 31.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/DBD/DB2.pm line 31.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl64/site/lib/DBD/DB2.pm line31.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 5) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
```

#### Environment information

- Windows7 64bit
- DB2 Client v10.5(fp8) 64bit
- Perl v5.20(64bit)
- DBD::DB2 Driver(32bit)
- http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/

#### Perl -v

```
This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 1 (v5.20.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

#### Perl -V

```
  Platform:
    osname=MSWin32, osvers=6.1, archname=MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
    uname=''
    config_args='undef'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=undef
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
```

#### Perl DB2 connect source

```perl
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:DB2:$databaseName", $userName, $password);
```

Comment: What kind of repository is this bribes.org?

Comment: @simbabque: It's a fairly ordinary PPM repository maintained by a private individual. I'm not sure what you want to know.

Comment: If you're using 64-bit perl, you're probably better off using 64-bit DBD::DB2. Either that or use 32-bit perl.  While I think 64-bit Windows processes can load 32-bit DLLs, I'm not sure if IBM has tested that combination or if perl/DBI need to do something special for it.

Comment: @Borodin I had never heard of it. The name rang an alarm bell.

Comment: @simbabque: It's good. It's French, and managed by *J-L Morel*. It has been around for years. [Take a look](http://www.bribes.org/perl/)

Comment: @Borodin ah, thanks. Yeah, it looks like it's real by the lack of looks. :D

Comment: Thanks to everyone for comment.

Comment: @simbabque:
This repository is described in the IBM Site DBD :: DB2 Driver 32bit.
command->ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/DBD-DB2.ppd

Comment: @Tanktalus: 
Perl used is 32 bit, so 32 bit DLL is used.
For that reason, I am trying to use a 32-bit DLLs.
I'm sorry. I have not been able to investigate whether IBM is also testing.

Comment: @User1115 you've installed to c:\perl64, which indicates 64-bit. Further, and more definitively, the "x64" in your perl -v output also indicates it's 64-bit.

Comment: @Tanktalus:Thanks for your comment.
I installed the DBD :: DB2 driver 64bit.
And When I run this I get a popup that says the "Perl interpreter has stopped working" and a button to close the program.
I do not understand the reason at all.